# How to deal with similar validation rules in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have not so much practical experience with Laravel yet and I wondered what is the best way to deal with similar validation logic and where to put it.

Let's say I have an API resource Controller for Products with a store and an update method like so:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:100',
        'description' => 'nullable|string|max:1000',
        'price' =>'required|decimal:0,2|lt:1000'
    ]);

    return Product::create($request->all());
}

public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'string|max:100',
        'description' => 'nullable|string|max:1000',
        'price' =>'decimal:0,2|lt:1000'
    ]);

    return Product::update($request->all());
}
```

The only difference between the validation in store and update is that store adds the 'required' rule for 'name' and 'price'. My question is, if I can encapsulate both validations in one Form Request, or how can I avoid code duplication without adding unnecessary code?

With my understanding of Form Requests I would probably create two Form Request classes, StoreProductRequest and UpdateProductRequest, and maybe another helper class that defines the core validation rules. Then each Form request could call for example ProductHelper::getBaseValidationRules() and merge that with their extra requirements. Somehow I find that a bit overkill.

Comment: You can create a function rules($request,$action) where $action can be 'update' or 'store' for example. And inside you make an if statement to add the required rule

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `request` for your validations and use them in your controllers

for example

```
php artisan make:request YOUR_REQUEST_NAME
```

then inside your request you can add your validations like this

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'description' => 'nullable|string|max:1000',
            'price' => 'required|decimal:0,2|lt:1000'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

and in your method you can call it like this

```
public function update(YOUR_REQUEST_NAME $request, Product $product)
{
    return Product::update($request->all());
}
```

for more information you can read this
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation
in case you want condition in the rules please check this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epMaClBOlw0&ab_channel=CodeWithDary

Comment: But I don't want the 'required' rule in update, only in store. So it should be possible to update only the name for example. But in store i need name and price for every request.

Comment: @Timo Assuming that a form is shown when you go to update an entry, if you give the form inputs the value already stored for them, you can still put the `required` rule in both `update` and `store` since it will pass the rule anyway. Just make sure the value is the already saved value and you wouldn't have to bother with 2 different form requests.

Comment: @geertjanknapen yes good idea. But I build an API so it would be nice to be independent from the consumers.

Comment: @Timo Right, did not catch that part. In that case you could look into the `sometimes()` validation which will only validate if the field is present, check out the [Sometimes validation rule documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-when-present) here.

Comment: in that case you can see this video it will help you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epMaClBOlw0&ab_channel=CodeWithDary

Answer (score 0):

Okay based on the suggestions, I came up with the following solution:

I created a Form Request named ProductRequest and implemented the rules method as follows:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'name' => ['string', 'max:100'],
        'description' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:1000'],
        'price' => ['decimal:0,2', 'lt:1000'],
    ];

    // If the user wants to create a new Instance some fields are mandatory.
    if ($this->method() === 'POST') {
        $rules['name'][] = 'required';
        $rules['price'][] = 'required';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

This is fine for me. Although in a bigger project I probably would create two Form Requests, StoreProductRequest and UpdateProductRequest. They would share and update a base set of rules as I described in the question.